# Force writing of default attribute values to xml file

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd

I am working on a system that loads from and writes to XML files, it also parses these files in an a schema aware manor. However I need to interface with schema unaware applications. When I save my files using

```
XmlDocument doc = #code that loads the document from disk
doc.Save();
```

The resulting XML file does NOT contain the default attributes on elements that do not specify them. How can I get the output to include unspecified attributes with their default values?

One solution I have that does work is looping through all elements, and every attribute on each element, then setting the attribute's value to itself e.g.:

```
#pseudocode
for element in document
    for attribute in element
        attribute.Value = attribute.Value;
```

This seems very wrong though, and it trips up code inspection because this should by all means be a useless assignment with no effect. But by some strange side effect it does mean that when I save the document the attributes are no included. How can I be more explicit about this?

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this situation before. Many XML processors offer schema-aware parsing, but not many include schema-aware serialisation. I'm not sure why, because the two are not so different technically.

One solution that I've seen is

- construct the DOM tree and serialise it (no defaults are applied)
- re-parse the resulting XML document (defaults get applied, and appear in the DOM tree)
- re-serialise the DOM (which now contains the defaults)#

It's not at all efficient, but it is *much* more maintainable (and probably more accurate) than the approach that you are currently using.